# Why is Angular calling `registerOnChange` after `ngOnDestroy` on custom ControlValueAccessor component?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-forms, angular12, controlvalueaccessor

After creating a custom form element, I noticed that when I navigated away from a route that hosted that custom form element, Angular would call the form element's `ngOnDestroy` method and then it would call the form element's `registerOnChange` and `registerOnTouched` methods. I'm not sure why it would call these two methods at this point, but I definitely don't understand why it would call them ***after*** `ngOnDestroy`.

I've created a minimal reproduction of this bug here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6jhgh6

This behavior is problematic for me because in my actual application, I'm destroying an instance of a CodeMirror editor and setting the variable reference to `null`, but in the `registerOnTouched` method, I reference that variable. This results in a null reference error. This just started happening after upgrading to Angular 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `registerOnChange` and `registerOnTouched` methods after the component's `ngOnDestroy` hook has been invoked is a consequence of calling `FormControlName.ngOnDestroy()`.

When a view is destroyed, my understanding from [this **function**](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/render3/node_manipulation.ts#L497) is that all of the `onDestroy` hooks from the destroyed view will be invoked. So, that's why the form directives of that view will have their `onDestroy` hook called too.

This is what happens on [`FormControlName.ngOnDestroy()`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/reactive_directives/form_control_name.ts#L157-L161):

```js
// `formDirective` refers to the parent `FormGroup` directive
this.formDirective.removeControl(this);
```

This is what happens on [`FormGroupDirective.removeControl()`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/reactive_directives/form_group_directive.ts#L187-L190):
:

```js
removeControl(dir: FormControlName): void {
  cleanUpControl(dir.control || null, dir, /* validateControlPresenceOnChange */ false);
  removeListItem(this.directives, dir);
}
```

And finally, [`cleanUpControl`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/shared.ts#L52-L63) is where the `registerOnChange` and `registerOnTouched` methods are invoked from:

```js
// Reverts configuration performed by the `setUpControl` control function.
// Effectively disconnects form control with a given form directive.
// This function is typically invoked when corresponding form directive is being destroyed.
export function cleanUpControl(/* ... */) {
  /* ... */
  const noop = () => {
    if (validateControlPresenceOnChange && (typeof ngDevMode === 'undefined' || ngDevMode)) {
      _noControlError(dir);
    }
  };

  if (dir.valueAccessor) {
    dir.valueAccessor.registerOnChange(noop);
    dir.valueAccessor.registerOnTouched(noop);
  }
  /* .... */
}
```

So, based on my understanding, it is part of the *cleanup mechanism*. It is indeed a bit inconvenient because those methods are called when the view is set up and also when the view is destroyed. I guess the solution is to first check for null/undefined values.

If you want to explore further, you can just use the `debugger` keyword:

```js
registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
  debugger;
  this.con.log(`registerOnChange (${this.id})`);
}
```

and then open the DevTools in the StackBlitz project.